# Breakpoints not hit when trying to do remote debug in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, cucumber

I am running the following command on command prompt 
`mvnDebug cuke4duke:cucumber`

and then trying to attach from IntelliJ to remote debug code.
I get the following messages in InteliJ but breakpoint's never get hit
`Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8000', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8000', transport: 'socket'`

Note - My code is not stale, it is upto date.

Comment: Can you clarify: when do you get the disconnected message? Is it immediately, or is it only when you stop the debugger? Also, do you have any other jvm processes running on port 8000, and is your mvnDebug correctly binding the jvm debugging port to 8000?

Comment: It does not get disconnected immediately, it is only when I stop the debugger. There is no other jvm process running on port 8000. mvnDebug seems to be correctly binding but i think since it is running as a seperate process maybe remote debugging is hitting some issue.